# how to calculate limits of greatest integer function

Tags: limits

I'm really confused, how can we calculate the limit of greatest integer function where the variable tends to infinity? Like for eg i had this question $\frac{\lfloor{(3x-2}\rfloor}{(2x+1)}$. A hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use squeeze theorem by bounding the floor function.

Comment: oh, are there any extra rules for these kind of questions? Or maybe i can just start like any other question?

Comment: Squeeze Theorem is one of those standard rules to evaluate limits. It is not an extra.

Comment: Yes i got you. thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x-1\leq \lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$, for $x>0$ we have
$$\frac{3x-3}{2x+1} \leq \frac{\lfloor 3x-2 \rfloor}{2x+1} \leq \frac{3x-2}{2x+1}$$
The limit of the left and right expressions as $x$ goes to infinity is $\frac 3 2$, so the same holds for the middle, by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: woah, nice gotcha. Thanks mate :)